# Rows with text in QListWidget (using setItemWidget) stops wrapping and become wider than the list can hold

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5, qlistwidget

I have a `QListWidget` and am using `setItemWidget()` to display `QLabels` which are wrapped with `setWordWrap()`.

The problem I have is that the width of the rows become wider than can fit inside the QListWidget when I have a text which is more than about 480 px wide for one of the rows in the table.

When resizing the list I get this behavior: If I resize and the row width is more than 480 px the words will "move between lines" as expected because of the word wrap. But if I am below 480 px in width there is no difference: wrapping is done but the word length of the lines doesn't change.

### Examples

#### Approx. 480 px wide row

[image]

#### Wider than 480

[image]

#### Narrower than 480

[image]

### Additional details

When I am working with rows where there are less characters in the `QLabels` the problem is still there but not until the rows are narrower than before (less than 480). The number of pixels where the problem starts  occurring is dynamic and is depending on the number of characters in the text. 480 seems to be an upper limit though, in other words no matter the length of the text there will never be a problem if the rows are 480 or more wide.

Example with a shorter text:

[image]

### Code

```
list_item = QListWidgetItem()
row_layout = QHBoxLayout()
label = QLabel(label_text_sg)
label.setWordWrap(True)
row_layout.addWidget(row_label_w8)
row_widget = QWidget()
row_widget.setLayout(row_layout_l7)
row_widget.adjustSize()
list_item.setSizeHint(row_w6.sizeHint())
self.list_widget.addItem(list_item)
self.list_widget.setItemWidget(list_item, row_widget)
```

I've tried experimenting with `setSizePolicy` for `row_widget` and for  `label` but it doesn't seem to have any effect

Any ideas for what I can do to solve this problem? Grateful for help!

Respectfully and with kind regards,
Tord

Comment: Do you actually need to use a `QListWidget`? Why not use a `QScrollArea`?